set_time_limit(0) still cause time out error
I have a WordPress plugin that will process all the posts, so it will take a long time.
To prevent time out, I use the set_time_limit(0) in Prevent timeout during large request in PHP
But that does not work, after some time, I still get the following error:
504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.25.3

Our server configuration is Apache + Nginx + Cloudflare
Thanks
Update
Based on volkerschulz's suggestion, I plan to use CLI or WP_CLI to execute my script.
Currently my script is invoked in this way:
https://www.sample.com/blogs/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=dnip_myplugins&nocache=123

So for my case, should I use CLI like below:
PHP /path/to/script/admin-post.php?action=dnip_myplugins&nocache=123

Or use WP-CLI:
I cannot find a command that can execute a script. The only one related is wp plugin, but it can only install/activate/deactive plugins



I think nginx has claimed responsibility for this error.

@shingo is exactly right: it's probably nginx' fastcgi_read_timeout setting. It's not the best idea to call (long running) maintenance script through the web server though. Use the CLI oder WP-CLI.

@volkerschulz, Thanks. Just update the question regarding whetehr should I use CLI or WP-CLI.

As mentioned above, (long running) maintenance scripts should not be executed through the web server but directly via shell. The simplest way is probably creating a new PHP file (preferably above the web root) with the following contents:
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once '/path/to/wp-load.php';

//Call whatever function from WP core or plugin to do the maintenance task
MyCustomPluginClass::amazingMaintenanceStuff();

and then call that_script.php through the CLI (php that_script.php). This way you can also easily configure timeouts and memory limits for that script only.
Better yet (but a little more complicated) is to create a custom WP-CLI command or add a WP cron job that cannot be executed by users but only by WP-CLI via system's crontab.
